# Constrained Maximization in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I feel like this should be easy to solve, but I am just hitting a road block. Perhaps, I'm thinking about the problem all wrong. I want to find the max combination of three values subject to the sum of a fourth value.

Let me give an example:

```
        a  b  c  d

  1.    2  3  4  2
  2.    1  2  5  3
  3.    3  1  2  5
  4.    2  4  2  1
```

So max f(a,b,c) where f = a + b + c (one value from each column) s.t. 7 < SUM(d).
(7 was just a random number I chose)

Where the value of "d" is the "d" value from the same row as the "a", "b", or "c" value.

I feel like I'm explaining this poorly. Please forgive me.

I'm relatively new to R. When I was in school I would have used a Lagrangian to do budget constraints. But, it's been a while and I've never had to do this with specific values in a Data Set.

Comment: What does s.t. 7 mean? Can you please rewrite your question, it is a bit unclear although I think I understand. Can you share with us what you have tried so far?

Comment: do the a,b, and c need to come from different rows?  If so, and installing library `combinat` for `permn`, you could try `max(unlist(combn(nrow(dat), 3, FUN=function(x) with(list(samp=dat[x,]), lapply(combinat::permn(3), function(y) if (sum(samp[cbind(y,4)]) <= 7) 0 else sum(samp[cbind(y,1:3)]))))))`.  This will return 12, c from row 2, b from row 4, and a from row 3.  Note: don't load `combinat` via `library(combinat)` since it has a different version of `combn`

Comment: so you have a constrained linear programming problem, surely you don't have to solve that from scratch. you should look up the package `lpSolve` - http://lpsolve.r-forge.r-project.org/